# How to determine the dimension of a row space.

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

Okay so I'm doing a question where first it asks you to state a row space of a matrix and then find the dimension of this row space. I have the row space as

$$row(\textbf{A})=span\{(1,-1,3,0,-2),(2,1,1,-2,0),(-1,-5,7,4,-6)\}$$

I know that finding a basis for this set is what is needed then simply counting the number of vectors in the set will give me the answer but I don't know how to proceed.

thanks.

Comment: Hint: See if the three vectors in your span are linearly independent or not. If they are, the dimension is 3. If they are not, then check every possible pairs from that 3. If at least one pair is independent, then the dimension is 2. If not, then 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stick those three rows into the rows of a matrix and then use row reduction.  If you get any rows with all zeroes then throw them out, otherwise your three rows are already linearly independent.

$$\pmatrix{1 & -1 & 3 & 0 & -2 \\ 2 & 1 & 1 & -2 & 0 \\ -1 & -5 & 7 & 4 & -6}$$

Can you do the row reduction yourself?

Comment: Actually not how is the best way to tackle the row reduction?

Comment: should I try and get zeroes along the bottom then?

Comment: I just looked at the question and it actually asks me to state the dimension before even finding a basis (that's the second part of the question) so is it after a different method.

Comment: You can do row reduction to get them both at the same time.  You don't remember Gauss-Jordan elimination?

Comment: Yes okay thanks, I'm just wondering if the question is actually hinting at something else as it also asks for a basis for col(A) and it seems a lot of work for only a couple of marks.

Comment: Gauss-Jordan elimination will *also* will tell you a basis for the column space -- it really is the best method to get *all* of the relevant details out of a matrix.

Comment: Okay I did that and got $$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 3 & 0 & -2\\ 
0 & 3 & -5 & -2 & 4\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$ as my matrix. So does that mean that the dimension of row(A) is 2 and the basis is the first 2 rows of my original matrix? Then dimension of Col(A) is 5 and its basis is the 5 column vectors in the original matrix?? But I thought dim(col(A))=dim(row(A)) so what is wrong????

Comment: First question: Yes (you could also use the nonzero rows here as your basis assuming you reduced it correctly -- and in general you should use the reduced rows).  Second: No.  Third: It does.  What is wrong is that to find the column space by looking at the RREF (this isn't quite the RREF, but it's close enough) you look at the pivot positions.  In this case the pivots are in columns $1$ and $2$ (so the dimension of the column space is $2$ as well).   Then your column space is the span of the first and second columns of your *original* matrix.

Comment: Okay thanks. By pivots do you mean the first non-zero number in a row?

Comment: Yep.  And if you have it in RREF, those first nonzero numbers will be $1$'s.

Comment: @James If you got the answer using my or abel's help you could accept one of our answers.

Comment: You're welcome.  :)

Answer (score 0):

if you look at the last three components of your row vectors $a = (1, -1, 3,0,-2), b = (2, 1, 1,-2,0), c = (-1, -5, 7,4,-6),$ then you find that $3a - 2b = c$ but the first two components too satisfy this relation. so the three rows are linearly dependent. the dimension of the row space is $2$ because $b$ is certainly not a multiple of $a.$

i chose to look at the last three components because of the zeros in $b$ and $c.$